# React Router. go back if RouteHandler throws exception

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I wonder how to correctly go back/fall back to previous route if the one we try to transition to failed to render?

I have a use case with data that should be fetched before rendering the page(RouteHandler), but what if it can't be rendered due to exception on the API.

[Just a simple example](https://github.com/yahoo/flux-examples/tree/master/react-router), if we add `throw new Error('demo error')` in any *render* function of *RouteHandler* and navigate to it, we get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_currentElement' of null
```

then if you try to go to some other route it will not render even though it doesn't have exceptions. It sort of breaks everything because it can't unmount what was never rendered/mounted and the same `Cannot read property '_currentElement' of null` exception appears again. Is the best solution to just wrap all *render* functions in try-catch and `return false`?